# How to check if SQL Server BIDS is installed

Tags: ssis, bids

i want to create sql server integration service package by the use of Business Intelligence Development Studio but don't know why this studio is not getting open from sql server group, only command window gets open and suddenly closed, whether BIDS is installed or not how to check it, please help me for the same.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIDS is Visual Studio. You need to go into the SQL SERVER setup and check if the Development tools are installed.

1. Check which version of SQL Server you have
2. Run the installer package.
3. Click through to amend the set up
4. Ensure that the Development Tools are installed

Install any Visual studio service packs.

Comment: i am using server 2008, bids is showing within server studio group...i have to again run installer package?

Comment: it's the best way to check if it's installed.

Comment: thanks sir i repaired server and its done..thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 6):

I can install applications, but do not have the SQL Server installer package. To run it, I'd have to log a trouble ticket and wait for support help. In these circumstances, the approach that worked best was:

1. Open Visual Studio (2012, in my case).
2. Select the **File** menu
   **New Project...** option. This opens the **New Project** dialog.
3. If necessary, expand the **Installed** item in the left hand column.
4. Likewise, expand **Templates**.

If you see **Business Intelligence** listed here, you're probably in good shape. More specifically, after BIDS installation, my Visual Studio installation lists business intelligence template subcategories:

- **Analysis Services**
- **Integration Services**
- **Reporting Services**

(This is where my screen shot belongs, but I don't have the reputation points required to post it yet! Maybe later, if fate is kind.)

If you don't see this, download the [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence project template installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) and run it. (The link is to the Visual Studio 2012 English version, so you may need to search for the corresponding version.)